# Bootstrap horizontal forms don't work on localhost IIS

Tags: asp.net, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

This html for a horizontal form works fine on bootply, but not so much on my IIS server.  Edit: Instead of horizontal, like on every other bootstrap horizontal form example on the interweb, the label always appears left justified to edge of the page and the input is directly below it.  This happens in both Chrome and IE11.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="control-group">            
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txtFindClinician">Find a Clinician</label>            
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="txtFindClinician" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="enter a name" name="search" />        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to fetch thte relevant CSS, yes? Can you confirm (chrome developer) that they're actually coming through?

Comment: Also, try to be more specific as to what the issue is, "don't work" does not give us much to go on...

Comment: @Jonathan:  You're right, I was pointing at the wrong folder for the CSS. In developer tools on the network tab, the call to the CSS file returned a 404.  If you answer the question, I'll mark your answer.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to fetch the relevant CSS, yes? Can you confirm (perhaps via chrome developer) that they're actually coming through?